# Get custom category attribute value

Tags: magento-1.9, category, eav, custom-attributes

I have created a custom category attribute using this tutorial http://gauss-development.com/blog/tutorials/adding-custom-category-attributes-magento/.

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$attribute  = array(
    'type'          =>  'text',
    'label'         =>  'Extra Title',
    'input'         =>  'text',
    'global'        =>  Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible'       =>  true,
    'required'      =>  false,
    'user_defined'  =>  true,
    'default'       =>  "",
    'group'         =>  "General Information"
);
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'cat_extra_title', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

I have checked that the attribute is stored in eav_attribute table normally, but I can't get it's value.

```
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
if ($category){
   $value = $category->getData('cat_extra_title'); //value is empty
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: which page you are showing the value?

Comment: First you try to print the values of the current category by using var_dump($category->getData()). Whether the values of 'cat_extra_title' is retrieving or not.

Comment: @Manikandan there are values retrieved but the 'cat_extra_title' value is not included in them. Why?

Comment: @QaisarSatti I'd like to retrieve this attribute value in a code file app/local/..., of a module that's been used to display the main menu.

Comment: Now you manually save the value for that attribute in magento admin panel. Then you print the var_dump . @ktsixit

Comment: @Manikandan The attribute value is saved ok in eav_attribute table. And it's displayed in category admin. I just can't get the attribute value with some coding.

Comment: try $category->getCatExtraTitle();

Comment: @Manikandan $category->getCatExtraTitle(); is not working.

Comment: Can you print the values and share the link

Comment: @Manikandan I can't share a link, but here's the var_dump($category->getData() contents:
http://i.imgur.com/e71ml8T.jpg

Comment: @Manikandan any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After testing many possible solutions, this was the only one that worked for me:

```
$cat_extra_title = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())->getData('cat_extra_title');
```

Comment: It's actually not a good practice to call "->load" every time when you need just one attribute. First of all - if you have Category Flat enabled (check in System - Configuration - Catalog) - do a reindex of Flat Category and check if column for your attribute appeared in flat table. And second - check my reply below

Comment: I was looking for something like this today and your solution works. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

when adding new attribute for Category or Product, we need to put this attribute in Attribute Set and Attribute Group.
So your code should look like this:

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'cat_extra_title', array(
    'type'              => 'text',
    'label'             => 'Extra Title',
    'input'             => 'text',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'required'          => false,
    'default'           => '',
    'user_defined'  =>  true,
    'default'       =>  "",
));
$entityTypeId     = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_category');
$attributeSetId   = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);
$installer->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'cat_extra_title'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue today. I created a new custom category attribute (an int/select one), and I would try this, in list.phtml, and get an empty value:

```
$value = Mage::registry('current_category')->getData('my_custom_Attribute');
```

However, this was solved by re-indexing `catalog_category_flat`; with n98:

```
n98-magerun.phar index:reindex catalog_category_flat
```

Now, the same code produces the value, *so long as a value exists for the category* (if the value is empty/NULL, then, of course, it will still produce a NULL value).